# Google Play downloads app to wrong tablet

Tags: applications, google-play-store

I bought my daughter an Android tablet and tried to download Angry Birds onto it.  It showed the message that app would be downloaded shortly, but it never did.  A little while later, I logged onto my tablet only to find it installed on MY tablet.  I thought maybe I had accidentally picked up the wrong tablet as they do look similar, so I tried it again.  Sure enough, go to google play on her tablet and it downloads the app onto mine.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Are using the Google Play app on your daughters tablet? Or on a PC?

Comment: Are you using the web interface to Google Play instead of the Play Store app?

Comment: Yes, using Web Interface

Comment: Are you logged into the right account?

Comment: @AlE. yes, I'm logged into the right account.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using the web interface (going to the Play store on your computer), there is an option to choose which device to download it to.

After you hit the green install button a window pops up. There will be a rectangle on top that has a list of permissions that the app requires. Underneath that is a drop down box that allows you to choose which device (out of all the devices connected to your account) to install the app to.

If you have the same model tablet as your daughter it may take some experimenting to figure out which is which. You can rename the devices (to make it easier to know which one you want to download to) by going to settings (the gear looking icon on the top right side).

Edit:

```
  If you do not see both tablets in the drop down or under the settings menu you 
need to check the tablets themselves to make sure they are both connected to the 
same Google account. This is located in different places on different tablets, 
but you can usually find it in the tablets settings under accounts.
```

Update:

```
try this link: 
http://androidforums.com/google/625570-can-you-sideload-google-play-app.html 
it explains how to side load the Google Play store. Here is a summary:
```

> "Download the matching .apk off the web onto your computer. (google
>   search it, use sources like XDA instead of 4shared or other sources
>   that could have viruses)
>
> Mount your phone as hard drive (when you plug in the USB cable to your
>   phone should give you the choice between charge only or mount as hard
>   drive). Put the .apk onto the SD Card where you can find it.
>
> Download a file manager off of Getjar, anything will work.
>
> Then go to settings>apps>allow external sources. Assuming your device
>   allows it, this will let you install non market/getjar apps. It might
>   be disabled already, thats OK.
>
> Find the file and tap on it. It'll show a list of permissions, or
>   things that the play store can do on your phone (like access the
>   internet, save files onto your phone, etc). just hit okay, or install.
>
> After that it should install for you, and you'll be able to find play
>   store in your app drawer like any other app.
>
> Here's a link to the play store. Download the unmodded version.
>   http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1582422"

Comment: Tried to do this, but new tablet is not showing in the list, only the old one

Comment: Did you create a Google account on the new tablet? Have you tried launching the *Google Play Store* app on it, connect to the Playstore, and download/install an app from it that way?

Comment: How do I install the google play store app if I can't install any apps?

Comment: @Kevin You said that you and your daughter have identical tablets. If she has the app installed, then so do you. Even if I misunderstood and you have different tablets, most tablets come with the google play store app pre-installed. It's not a matter of installing it, it's a matter of launching the app and connecting your account. What tablet do you have (make and model please)?

Comment: @Lazer they are not identical.  And her's does not have google play installed.  This is the tablet:http://www.hhgregg.com/klu-by-curtis-7-4gb-android-4-1-touchscreen-tablet/item/LT7035

Comment: @Kevin, I changed my answer to include instructions on how to add the Google Play store to your daughters tablet.